# Tomato firmware - how to setup public wifi with login page

Tags: wireless-networking, tomato

I have flashed tomato firmware on my Linksys E3200 router. I want to setup a public wifi (no password) like Target free wifi: when user goes to any webpage for the first time he will be redirected to a login page. Is this possible with Tomato firmware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Head on over to this page: http://tomatousb.org/forum/t-381082/tomato-captive-portal-splash-page-redesigned, this is the functionality you are looking for.